# Methods for measuring snowball effects in a "complete" longitudinal dataset

Tags: time-series, spss, autocorrelation, panel-data, autoregressive

I'm looking for ways to test for "cumulative advantage" effects in a longitudinal dataset (see image)

[image: Data set example]

I guess the data set is principally similar to this: http://www.caldercenter.org/whatis.cfm , but to be precise, the figures are weekly marked shares of a fixed selection of products. The full data set contains nearly 25,000 products tracked over 76 weeks.

What I want to investigate is:

1. Whether the rate of growth in marked share is a function of current values of marked share.
2. Whether small "advantages" at an early stage grow larger over time.

I have basic command of SPSS and methods like correlation and regression, and have some rough ideas like e.g. for each week "manually" measure the correlation between the (accumulated) marked share and the marked share of the following week, but I'm quite sure better suited approaches exsist. Could someone please be so kind as to point me to possibly fruitful directions?